# Metropolis-Hastings and underlying Markov process

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, simulations, molecular-dynamics

I tried to understand the workings of the Metropolis-Hasting algorithm.
As far as I can understand, it allows to draw samples from an unknown distribution $T(x)$ as long as a function proportional to it, $F(x)$ is known. In practice, it seems a great advantage is not to have to calculate the partition function $Z$.

The algorithm constructs a Markov process with transition probabilities $P_{ij}$ which is then made evolving to its stationary distribution $\pi$, which uniquely exists under some conditions.

**I would like to explicitly compute the transition matrix $P$** and find the stationary distribution solving a linear system.
The transition probability for Metropolis-Hastings is split in two steps,$P_{ij} = A_{ij} g_{ij}$,  getting a candidate via distribution $g$ and accepting/rejecting it according to $A$. Getting a candidate is done via a distribution, to be chosen, $g(j | i)$, giving the conditional probability of picking element $j$ if currently at $i$.
The acceptance $A_{ij}$ is defined as
$$A_{ij} = \min \Big( 1, \frac{F_j}{F_i)} \frac{g(i | j)}{g(j | i)}\Big) $$
As said $P_{ij} = A_{ij} g_{ij}$ and this is the transition matrix I would like to use, for example to calculate the stationary distribution $\pi$ using the equation $\pi P = \pi$.
I tried to apply this but I am not getting it to work.
I present the simplest example.
I have a particle that can be in one of four positions $1,2,3,4$, [image: toy canonical Markov Chain]

The energy level of each position equals $0,1,2,-1$ respectively.
In the canonical setting, the stationary distribution should be, taking the inverse temperature $\beta = 1$ for simplicity
$$ F_i = \frac{\exp\big(- \beta E_i\big)}{Z} $$
and $$Z = \exp\big(0  \big) + \exp\big(- 1 \big) + \exp\big(-2  \big) + \exp\big(1  \big)$$
As far as $g$ is concerned, I assume that only nearest-neighbour (imagining the $1,2,3,4$ configurations are located on a ring) jumps as well as jumps to the current position are possible, and they are all equiprobable.
Then $g$ could be represented as a matrix
$$ \begin{equation*}
g_{ij} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1/3 & 1/3 & 0 & 1/3 \\
1/3 & 1/3 & 1/3 & 0 \\
0 & 1/3 & 1/3 & 1/3 \\
1/3 & 0 & 1/3 & 1/3
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*} $$

It seems I am already going wrong here, as looking at the formula for $A$ one needs $g$ never to $0$, but surely there must some subtlety I am missing here, as I have seen Metropis-Hasting applications using nearest-neighbour jumps only, at least I think so...

Coming to the $A_ij$, it seems to me that it is either $1$, if $E_j<E_i$, else equal to $\exp(E_j-E_i)$.

Putting it all together, the transition probability matrix should be

$$ \begin{equation*}
P = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1-\exp(-1)/3- \exp(1)/3&  \exp(-1)/3 & 0 & \exp(1)/3 \\
1/3 & 2/3 - \exp(-1)/3 & \exp(-1)/3 & 0 \\
0 & 1/3 & 2/3 - \exp(-1)/3 & \exp(-1)/3 \\
\exp(1)/3 & 0 & \exp(-3)/3 & 1-\exp(1)/3-\exp(-3)/3
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*} $$

But it does not satisfy the equation $\pi P = \pi$ that is should if $\pi$ is to be the stationary distribution.

What is that I could be doing wrong?

What is also bugging me as mad is that the stationary distribution according to the exact canonical calculation should equal

[0.23688282, 0.08714432, 0.0320586 , 0.64391426]

while computing $\pi P$ I get

[0.10120567, 0.08714432, 0.03881357, 0.77283644]

the second element being identical!

I would be glad to share a simple Python snippet that performs the calculation, if anybody were interested at all, thanks

Comment: There is some imprecision in notation, as you denote states sometimes by $i,j$ and sometimes by $x_i,x_j$. The point of MH is that the desired distribution is the equilibrium distribution of the Markov chain, which has therefore to be made reversible (it cannot get stuck in a state) - this is usually imposing the *detailed balance* condition, $W_{ij}p_i=W_{ji}p_j$, which is implicit in the acceptance probability. I am posting this as a comment, since it is hard to follow through the formulae in the question. It could be better, if you focus on conceptual points.

Comment: @RogerVadim, thanks for this, well I though $I,j$ represent states, and $x_i, x)j$ represent their coordinate that is relevant for the energy, I will improve it. For the second part, I am not sure I see where you are tending. Detailed Balance as you say is implicit in the acceptance probability, that is properly how Metropolis is built. I want to build a Markov chain with the same stationary distribution. MH is sampling a Markov process, I want the proper transition matrix, I cannot figure out why it is not working (apart from the dubious choice of $g$ maybe, zero somewhere).

Comment: @RogerVadim, the fact is I thought I had a good grasp of the concepts, until I put it to the test with an example. Would you please tell which formulae are not clear, for me to improve their clarity? I must be missing something but I think working out a trivial concrete example must be the best way to get rid of the misunderstanding. From the abstract point of view, I went numerous times through the derivation I feel I got it fully, but it is clearly not so if I cannot work out a 4x4 stochastic matrix. If you let me know where to improve the question, I would be delighted to do so.

Comment: There seems to be quite a few typos in your equations: the energies in the partition function are different from those cited in the sentence above, and $g_{ij}$ has zeros in different places in the last equation and the one before the last... or is the last one for $A_{ij}$? Anyhow, the first $g_{ij}$ seems to have has wrong positions of zeros for detailed balance.

Comment: @RogerVadim ok thanks I made those corrections and still checking thoroughly. The $g_ij$ are now correct ( the four states are on a ring).

Comment: The rows in the last equation should some to one due to normalization - I think something is broken there. (Sorry, I am not behind my desk today, so I can't go through it with pen and paper.)

Comment: Also, if you add the python code, I might look into it.

Comment: The sketch is not related to the transition probabilities, right? Your sketch shows a system that is intrinsically out of equilibrium. If you can jump from state 1 to state 2 but the reverse path is forbidden, then your stationary solution for the probability includes a probability flux (detailed balance is broken). The metropolis-Hastings algorithm just applies (as far as I know) to equilibrium distributions.

Comment: @Javi, you are right in pointing out this aspect. The sketch is just meant to give some visual representation of the states. Reverse path do always exist in the example I considered for any $ i \to j$ there is a $j \to i$. The sketch should be corrected but it was getting surprisingly messy

Comment: I fear I found the mistake, element $1,4$ of the $P$ matrix above should be $1/3$, not $\exp(1)$, as the energy level 4 is lower than 1. Found it while cleaning the code up for posting. Will check thoroughly everything and edit, such a silly thing to overlook but the I got stuck over it for 2 days, getting old, my apologies to all

Comment: @Smerdjakov Classic! Hope that everything goes smoothly now :)

Answer (score 3):

I will answer as I found the mistake, my apologies for having been careless in posting I can assure you I spent much time doing hand calculations but sometimes things just evade your attention.

The entry $P_{14}$ in the probability matrix is wrong, should equal $1/3$  as the energy level $E_1$ is large than $E_4$. The method works, which is of course not surprising as it is based on MCMC definitions.

For completeness I attach the code that I put together and a bug of which started the whole question. It is not corrected and one can check in the last line that indeed the stationary distribution calculated via the canonical distribution, $p_0$ equals the stationary distribution $\pi$ of the Markov chain, satisfying $\pi P = \pi$

````
import numpy as np
#from scipy import linalg
energyLevels = np.array([0.,1.,2.,-1.],dtype=np.double)
BoltzFactors = np.exp(-energyLevels,dtype=np.double)
Z = np.sum(BoltzFactors,dtype=np.double)
# Canonical Distribution
p0 = np.exp(-energyLevels) / Z
AdjMat = np.array([[1,1,0,1],[1,1,1,0],[0,1,1,1],[1,0,1,1]])

# Assembly Transition Probability Matrix given adjacency matrix Adjmat, 
# this dummy case assumes there are 3 transitions possible per vertex
def MarkovTrans(AdjMat, energyLevels):
    ProbTrans = np.zeros((4,4))
    aux = AdjMat - np.diag(np.ones(4))
    indeces = np.argwhere(aux!=0)
    for i in range(indeces.shape[0]):
        ProbTrans[indeces[i][0],indeces[i][1]] = ( (1/3)*AdjMat[indeces[i][0],indeces[i][1]]*
            np.minimum (  1, np.exp(-(energyLevels[indeces[i][1]] - energyLevels[indeces[i][0]]))))
        ProbTrans = ProbTrans 
    for i in range(AdjMat.shape[0]):
        ProbTrans[i,i] = 1 - np.sum(ProbTrans[i,:])
    return ProbTrans
PP = MarkovTrans(AdjMat, energyLevels)
#Check if Markov stationary distribution equals p0
np.allclose(np.matmul(np.transpose(PP), np.transpose(p0) ),p0)
(*** TRUE ****)
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Jumps between energy levels are not equally probabilistic, your transition matrix is just too arbitrary.
First according to your definition $g_{ij}$ means that the particle was previously at energy level i and then transitioned to energy level j.Then the equilibrium distribution is set to $F_i = e^{-E_i}$, which does not need to be normalized. 
At this time, the transformation matrix needs to meet two conditions: The first is
$$ \sum_{j=1}^4 g_{ij} = 1$$
It means that the particle's previous position is deterministic, whether it stays in place or transitions to another energy level next.
The second is:
$$ \sum_{j=1}^4 g_{ij} e^{-E_j} = e^{-E_i}  $$
It means that the delicate balance condition has been met at this time. Your transition matrix needs to be solved under these two conditions, I totally don't understand how you can arbitrarily write a transition matrix ignoring the second condition, which doesn't even satisfy this condition at all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Both those conditions are enforced, the first on $g$ by my closest-neighbour jump assumption, and the second one implicitly by the Metropolis Hasting algorithm. I calculate the elements of the transitions matrix using $P_{ij} = A_{ij} g{ij}$ and the $A_{ij}$ ar calculated using the Metropis Hasting equation, first equation at the beginning of the post. the methods works as it must, I was messing it up with a silly mistake, sorry for the confusion.