# Regarding Metropolis-Hasting Algorithm

Tags: statistical-mechanics, computational-physics

This is motivated by this post [Metropolis-Hastings and underlying Markov process](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/710172/metropolis-hastings-and-underlying-markov-process). I am also trying to compute the stationary state of the Boltzman distribution by the method discussed in the post. Here, I am considering three states A, B and c with energies $-1, 0, 1$ respectively. For matrix G, I am assuming every state is equally probable from every state. In other words, every element of G is $\frac{1}{3}$. Then the transition matrix $P$ is,
\begin{pmatrix}
1-\frac{1}{3e}-\frac{1}{3e^2} & \frac{1}{3e} & \frac{1}{3e^2}\\
        \frac{1}{3} & 1-\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{3e}& \frac{1}{3e} \\
        \frac{1}{3e^2} & \frac{1}{3e} & 1-\frac{1}{3e}-\frac{1}{3e^2}  \
        \end{pmatrix}
Directly using the partition function, $P(A), P(B), P(C)$ are approximately $0.66,0.24,  0.09$ respectively. Since the above matrix was constructed using the Metropolis Algorithm, the elements of eigen vector with eigen value $1$ of $P^T$should also be $0.66,0.24,  0.09$ but I get them to be $0.5, 0.2, 0.3$ Below I have attached an image of that computation. I have no idea what went wrong here.
[[image]]

Comment: I noticed the mistake. It was a calculation mistake. Elements $P_{31}$ and $P_{32}$ are wrong. They both are $\frac{1}{3}$ so the whole third row's element is $\frac{1}{3}$. Now I get the expected answer.